# NGINX set cookie based on value of a header

Tags: http, cookies, nginx, header

I'm trying to get NGINX to check if a request header `user_header_token` is present. If it is not present, redirect to the login site. If it is present, set a cookie with the header's value. The cookie is empty when it is set currently instead of the `$http_` variable I'm trying to set it to. Does anyone see what I'm doing that's preventing this this cookie from being set to the header's value?

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            if ($http_user_header_token = "") {
                rewrite ^.*$ https://loginsite.com/;
                return 403;
            }

            add_header Set-Cookie user_header_token=$http_user_header_token;

            root /usr/src/ui/;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of response are you getting? If there is an error in your response, you may need to add the `always` flag or the header may not be added.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

> Syntax:    add_header name value [always];
>
> If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code